# C# WinAppCalculator to WebAppCalculator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, calculator

Hi I am pretty new to coding especially in c# and have a problem with my project. I am looking to make a calculator online using c# and upload it to a database and host in azure. Here is my question:

I am having a problem with my c# code in Visual Studio using web forms. It is simply not working, It can input numbers and operations however does not get the correct result e.g. 3 + 3 = 33. This is a conversion from WinApp, so it may be from there? But I re-created the UI and repurposed the code to fit a online app. After I get this to work I plan on uploading it to azure. Is there any reason why this is not working? My WinApp in .NET has a very similar code and works so is it a .NET/ASP.net issue? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
public partial class WebForm1 : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["operationPerf"] = "false";
        ViewState["operation"] = string.Empty;
        ViewState["answer"] = "0";
    }
protected void NumbEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox.Text == "0" || bool.Parse(ViewState["operationPerf"].ToString()) == true)
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;

    Button butt = (Button)sender;
    textbox.Text += butt.Text;
    ViewState["operationPerf"] = false;

    label.Text = label.Text + " " + textbox.Text;
}

protected void OperandEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["operationPerf"] = true;
    Button butt = (Button)sender;
    string newOperand = butt.Text;

    label.Text = label.Text + " " + newOperand;

    switch (ViewState["operation"])
    {
        case "+":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) + Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) - Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "*":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) * Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "/":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) / Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "^":
            textbox.Text = (Math.Pow(Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])), Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
            break;
        case "√":
            textbox.Text = (Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    ViewState["answer"] = textbox.Text;
    ViewState["operation"] = newOperand;
}

protected void Bequal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["operationPerf"] = true;

    switch (ViewState["operation"])
    {
        case "+":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) + Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) - Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "*":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) * Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "/":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) / Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "^":
            textbox.Text = (Math.Pow(Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])), Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
            break;
        case "√":
            textbox.Text = (Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    label.Text = label.Text + " = " + textbox.Text;

    label.Text = "";
    ViewState["answer"] = textbox.Text;
    textbox.Text = ViewState["answer"].ToString();
    ViewState["answer"] = 0;
    ViewState["operation"] = "";
}

protected void BC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.Text = "0";
    label.Text = "";
    ViewState["answer"] = 0;
    ViewState["operation"] = "";
}
```

}

This is my original code before attempting to fix the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
public partial class WebForm1 : Page
{
    bool operationPerf = false;
    string operation = "";
    double answer = 0;

    protected void NumbEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox.Text == "0" || operationPerf)
            textbox.Text = string.Empty;

        Button butt = (Button)sender;
        textbox.Text += butt.Text;
        operationPerf = false;

        label.Text = label.Text + " " + textbox.Text;
    }

    protected void OperandEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operationPerf = true;
        Button butt = (Button)sender;
        string newOperand = butt.Text;

        label.Text = label.Text + " " + newOperand;

        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                textbox.Text = (answer + Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                textbox.Text = (answer - Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                textbox.Text = (answer * Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                textbox.Text = (answer / Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "^":
                textbox.Text = (Math.Pow(answer, Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
                break;
            case "√":
                textbox.Text = (Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        answer = Double.Parse(textbox.Text);
        operation = newOperand;
    }

    protected void Bequal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operationPerf = true;

        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                textbox.Text = (answer + Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                textbox.Text = (answer - Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                textbox.Text = (answer * Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                textbox.Text = (answer / Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "^":
                textbox.Text = (Math.Pow(answer, Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
                break;
            case "√":
                textbox.Text = (Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(textbox.Text))).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        label.Text = label.Text + " = " + textbox.Text;

        label.Text = "";
        answer = Double.Parse(textbox.Text);
        textbox.Text = answer.ToString();
        answer = 0;
        operation = "";
    }

    protected void BC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox.Text = "0";
        label.Text = "";
        answer = 0;
        operation = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're new to c#, unless you have a specific reason (like school assignment), I'd suggest you not to waste time with WebForms. That framework is dead and it has been for many years. You're going to have to learn a lot of stuff that will be pointless after you change to MVC or any other newer framework.

Comment: Thanks @CamiloTerevinto I am doing it for an assignment, I already have a working WinForms Calculator that I am converting to webforms to be published in azure afterwards. Do you have any suggestions at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting 33 as the result of 3 + 3 then that suggests to me that you're using the `+` operator on two strings (or maybe a string and a number) rather than two numbers, i.e. the `+` operator is doing string concatenation rather than addition.

If you use the `+` operator on two numbers (types such as `int`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`) then it adds the two numbers together as you'd expect.

However, if you use the `+` operator on

- two strings, or
- a string and an instance of something which has an implementation of the `ToString` method (which means pretty much anything which isn't a struct, because all classes in .net are derived from `object`, which has a `ToString` method)

then it concatenates the two strings, or the string and the return value of the other object's `ToString` method. (* see footnote)

I can't see in the code where this is happening, but I'd suggest a bit of refactoring which would make it easier to track down.

This switch block has quite a lot of repetition:

```
    switch (ViewState["operation"])
    {
        case "+":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) + Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textbox.Text = (Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"])) - Double.Parse(textbox.Text)).ToString();
            break;
```

All those calls to Double.Parse are going to return the same two values, regardless of which one is executed, so only make the calls once and cache the result, e.g.

```
    var answer = Double.Parse(Convert.ToString(ViewState["answer"]));
    var textboxValue = Double.Parse(textbox.Text);
    switch (ViewState["operation"])
    {
        case "+":
            textbox.Text = (answer + textboxValue).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textbox.Text = (answer - textboxValue).ToString();
            break;
```

This gives you shorter lines, easier to read, easier to spot any mistakes, and importantly there are fewer nested brackets. Transposing a bracket and a comma in a long and complex line of code, in the best case scenario causes a compiler error, but if it doesn't then it can cost hours of investigating why the application is misbehaving.

I also notice that this entire switch block appears to be repeated in both the OperandEvent and Bequal_Click methods. Do you need it in both? I can't tell from looking at the posted code, but it's something I'd suggest you think about. If you do need it in both, and it needs to behave identically in both, then move it into its own private method, and call that method from the OperandEvent and Bequal_Click methods.

May I draw your attention to the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/97-things-every/9780596809515/ch30.html) principle of software development?

> OF ALL THE PRINCIPLES OF PROGRAMMING, Don’t Repeat Yourself (DRY) is perhaps one of the most fundamental. The principle was formulated by Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas in The Pragmatic Programmer, and underlies many other well-known software development best practices and design patterns. The developer who learns to recognize duplication, and understands how to eliminate it through appropriate practice and proper abstraction, can produce much cleaner code than one who continuously infects the application with unnecessary repetition.
>
> Duplication Is Waste
>
> Every line of code that goes into an application must be maintained, and is a potential source of future bugs. Duplication needlessly bloats the codebase, resulting in more opportunities for bugs and adding accidental complexity to the system. The bloat that duplication adds to the system also makes it more difficult for developers working with the system to fully understand the entire system, or to be certain that changes made in one location do not also need to be made in other places that duplicate the logic they are working on. DRY requires that “every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system.”

Any time you find yourself writing more or less the same block of code more than once, you should ask yourself, "can I refactor this code into a new, shorter line, a new reusable method, or maybe even a new class?"

I hope you find this answer helpful, and wish you the best of luck in your studies.

#### Footnote

What I said about the behaviour of the `+` operator isn't the whole truth, because a class can explicitly define how the `+` and other operators behave when applied to an instance of that class (this is known as operator overloading). But you say you're new to programming, and this detail isn't really relevant to this question, so don't worry about it for now.

Comment: `Any time you find yourself writing more or less the same block of code more than once, you should ask yourself, "can I refactor this code into a new, shorter line, a new reusable method, or maybe even a new class?"` Sorry to say, but you've fallen into the same misunderstandings of DRY that many before you have: the principle is not about code dupication. It is about _business logic_ duplication. Refactoring to remove code duplication under the simplification of "duplication = bad" is what leads to giant types doing a thousand different things that are hard to change. There is a better way.

Comment: When you run into a situation where you're wondering if duplication is fine or not, ask yourself this question: "Should these two things be able to vary independently?" If the answer is `yes`, do nothing. If the answer is `no`, refactor to remove the duplication, assuming you have enough time, it's not unrelated to your work, and your changes would be small enough to review. If, for some reason, the answer is `I'm not sure`, do nothing, because you don't yet have enough information to make a decision. (You could of course speak with a teammate who may have more information than you do.)

Comment: And finally, what I've said above is captured, albeit not explicitly enough for my liking, by the final sentence you've quoted from the book: "DRY requires that “every piece of _knowledge_ must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system.”", with emphasis mine.

Comment: @sbridewll Thanks for your great suggestion! I agree that it is repetitive and needs some refactoring but The repetition I believe is needed. However I included my original code above before attempting to fix the issue the view states were implemented as I thought it may not be properly saving the first result. This has not fixed the issue so I will most likely revert back to the original. I agree that it could be trying to use the + operator to concatenate the two values but this is the same with all of the operators.

Comment: @liamw Try to separate your code's interaction with the UI from its business logic. So, if there's an answer in the UI and you want to work with it, then

`var answer = ViewState["answer"];`

and then use that variable in your business logic. That will help you to isolate problems with the UI framework you're working with from problems with your business logic.

Comment: @JohnH I agree with everything you've said here. My description of the DRY principle could have been better.